# Running a powershell script from a application pool user elevated priv

Tags: powershell, application-pool, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I have a specific scenario that's troubling me was hoping for some insight from the community.

I'm trying to run an add HTTPS binding & link to certificate PowerShell script via a web-application that is running on it's own application pool identity.

The PowerShell script requires elevated privilege's so it fails to run successfully and only gets to the bindings part but not the linking of the SSL certificate.

I cannot call to run a saved script file with my code because the bindings are dynamically generated on the fly and require the web-application to replace the token that holds the binding.

How can I successfully run the script below if it's ran via the web-application that is currently running it's application pool identity user? I've tried encompassing my script with an elevation tag but that fires a new elevated separate PowerShell window that doesn't work for me as this is all happening automatically without a user.

```
New-WebBinding -name "example.domain" -IPAddress "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" -Protocol https -HostHeader [DynamicallyLoadedViaWebApplication] -Port 443 -SslFlags 1
$siteName = 'example.domain'
$Cert = (get-item cert:"\LocalMachine\WebHosting\THUMBPRINTHERE")
$binding = Get-WebBinding -Name $siteName -Protocol "https"
$binding.AddSslCertificate($Cert.GetCertHashString(), "WebHosting")
```

I've tried shutting UAC off via the registry but that didn't help. The script above must be ran via the web-application with high enough privilege's to complete successfully

---

UPDATE:

Being that the 1st script to fire is done so via the `application pool identity` and not an administrator account is this method viable? I can eventually try switching the `application pool user` to an administrator but I'd like to avoid that if possible. Or any other ideas on how to do the binding via the `application pool` user?

Comment: Why can’t you run it as a saved script? You could pass the generated header in as a parameter.

Comment: @DougMaurer do you have any links or examples of how I could do that?

Comment: Is this something you’re needing to do often?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this somewhere the user account has access to. For this example I'll call it `sslscript.ps1` and save it to `c:\temp`

```
@'
Param($data)
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList @"
New-WebBinding -name "example.domain" -IPAddress "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" -Protocol https -HostHeader $data -Port 443 -SslFlags 1
$siteName = 'example.domain'
$Cert = (get-item cert:"\LocalMachine\WebHosting\THUMBPRINTHERE")
$binding = Get-WebBinding -Name $siteName -Protocol "https"
$binding.AddSslCertificate($Cert.GetCertHashString(), "WebHosting")
"@ -Verb runas
'@ | Set-Content c:\temp\sslscript.ps1 -Encoding UTF8
```

Call it from your application like this

```
c:\temp\sslscript.ps1 [DynamicallyLoadedViaWebApplication]
```

Here's a small test you can run as a proof of concept. This will invoke UAC so that may be the only issue I can foresee. If this turns out to be an issue then perhaps you can save the dynamically created info to a file and then run a scheduled task as admin and have it grab the info.

```
@'
    Param($data)
    Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList @"
    write-host Argument passed in: $data -foregroundcolor cyan
    `$isadmin = [bool](([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).groups -match 'S-1-5-32-544')
    if(`$isadmin)
    {
        write-host script is 'running as admin' -foregroundcolor green
    }
    else
    {
        write-host script is not 'running as admin' -foregroundcolor red
    }
    pause
"@ -Verb runas
'@ | Set-Content c:\temp\testscript.ps1 -Encoding UTF8

C:\temp\testscript.ps1 "passing in some data"
```

Output should look like
[image]

Comment: thank you for the detailed post, i'll do a test with this and see if it ends up working!

Comment: i was able to successfully launch the script via my application. I had to turn off UAC but it dosent seem to write my bindings. I'm running (`L:\mydrive\mypub\sslscript.ps1 subdomain.domain.com`)

Comment: Yeah chances are it's not elevating. How often are you going to have to do this? If it's infrequent, have a script output the dynamic info you're needing to a file. Then either run interactively or as a scheduled task. Is the user the apppool is running as a local admin on that box?

Comment: it's going to happen multiple times an hour if all goes according to plan. The identity within IIS shows `ApplicationPoolIdentity` I've not changed anything on it since it was created when initially adding my site to IIS. It seems that the 2nd script never runs.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in a similar problem, I've accepted Doug Maurer's answer as his method does work but in my specific scenario it didn't solve my problem so I'm posting if it helps anyone.

Since my website is executing the PowerShell command it fails to elevate regardless of the methodology used, unless someone else has some better way of doing this I don't know.

I ended up reverting to having my web application simply run the binding & SSL linking script itself without referencing any script file on disk.

IE:

```
New-WebBinding -name "example.domain" -IPAddress "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" -Protocol https -HostHeader [DynamicallyLoadedViaWebApplication] -Port 443 -SslFlags 1
    $siteName = 'example.domain'
    $Cert = (get-item cert:"\LocalMachine\WebHosting\THUMBPRINTHERE")
    $binding = Get-WebBinding -Name $siteName -Protocol "https"
    $binding.AddSslCertificate($Cert.GetCertHashString(), "WebHosting")
```

When doing this it fails if you keep the website's application pool default. I ended up creating a new local user on the server and making the user part of the `Administrators` group and then switching the `application-pool` for the website to run as this newly created user account. I had to restart the machine for it to actually take effect and work if you simply do this without restart it will still fail, at least it did for me.